# filtering `sexp` entries in org-agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, sexp

I have an org entry with a sexp and a tag:

```
* test  :test_tag:
%%(org-anniversary 2000 08 23) test anniversary
```

When I open my agenda "test anniversary" shows up as it should (I'm writing this on August 23rd).
But when I filter by it's tag (`/ -test_tag`) nothing happens!

How do I filter out `sexp` entries?

edit:

`emacs-version: GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) of 2019-09-16`

`org-version: Org mode version 9.3.2 (9.3.2-1-g1d426e-elpa @ /home/maynard/.emacs.d/elpa/org-9.3.2/)`

Comment: I cannot reproduce it: after the filter, the entry disappears from the agenda. Maybe edit your question and add versions (`M-x emacs-version` and `M-x org-version`), so we can check your particular version.

Comment: thanks for trying @NickD edited to add versions